Scalar QED atoms - will they pass through each other?
Atoms generally do not pass through each other. This is usually attributed to the Pauli exclusion principal between the electrons (see links below).
If the electrons and nucleons were switched with scalar particles, would these scalar-atoms pass through each other, or would we experience some normal force (would we still have solids)?
More concretely, how does the potential between these atoms look like as a function of distance, at short distances? does it diverge like the London force between actual atoms? (figure below)
My point is to figure out if the divergence of the potential between atoms at close range is due to the Pauli exclusion principal.

Discussions in which the Pauli exclusion principal was deemed responsible for atomic repulsion:
How can I stand on the ground? EM or/and Pauli?
Pauli exclusion principle and van der Waals force
The Lennard-Jones potential and the Pauli exclusion principle

btw: I answered the question in the affirmative, so I'll take that bounty now. Whether the theory is renormalizable or not is, ofc, irrelevant.

Hi @JEB. I think that the last part of your answer is relevant, but needs clarification. Why would these atoms pass eachother? Can you do some calculation that shows that the electrostatic forces do not have quantum terms that might arise in the case of fermions? I've clarified the question. You might consider writing a new answer with more detail towards atom interactions.

So we got scalar structure less charged colorless particles? The localized nuclei is where the strong field it, and they would scatter in the standard manner with zero phase space for $b=0$, but not for $b<\lambda_C$--so what does pass through even mean? If they are identical would they be in a symmetric wave function? Yes--then they wouldn't even have identity, so $t$ and $u$ channel are indistinguishable, there is no "atom 1" and "atom 2". Like I said: too hypothetical, but this is PSE, where it's OK to entertain silliness, since it can elucidate seriousness.

You should clarify what you mean by "passing through each other". Moreover, some atoms are globally fermions, others are bosons (take a look at the large topic of "ultracold" fermi and bose gases).

There are a few layers to this question. I'll try to address as many as I can.
To your concrete question about close-range atomic potentials, the divergence at short distances is entirely due to electrostatic repulsion between nuclei. Or at least this statement is unambiguously true for $\text{H}^2$. These atomic potentials can be computed using the Born-Oppenheimer approximation, in which nuclei are treated classically, and then we solve for the electronic wave functions and energies as a function of internuclear distance. In the case of hydrogen, Pauli exclusion plays no role in the calculation, because the bound state $\text{H}^2$ shows up when its two electrons are paired in the same orbital, one spin up and one spin down. The spatial wavefunctions are identical, and thus the Pauli exclusion principle does nothing to keep them apart.
However the story is more complicated for larger systems.
Turning to bosonic matter, it turns out that it is unstable. Wikipedia has the following equation, which makes this statement precise; for fermionic matter, the  lowest energy of a collection of $N$ electronics and $K$ nucleons satisfies
$$E_{N,K} \geq -(N+K) C$$
where $C$ is some constant. This means that binding energy is extensive, like we are used to. However if electrons were bosons, then it was shown that the right-hand side would scale like $N^{7/5}$, and therefore binding energy becomes superextensive. Thus if you had two chunks of bosonic matter and you brought them together, they would collapse into a much lower energy state and release a ton of energy. So while there are no normal forces, it's not like particles would just pass through each other.
So back to interactions between pairs of atoms; I suppose interpreting forces between atoms larger than hydrogen becomes a bit subtle. If you compute the energy of $\text{He}^2$ in the Born-Oppenheimer approximation, then the Pauli exclusion principle plays no role when the helium atoms are far apart, but certainly plays a role at small separations. If you turned off the Pauli exclusion principle and repeated the calculation, which you can absolutely do in non-relativistic problems like this, then you would get a different Born-Oppenheimer potential and it would almost certainly have a minimum at smaller separation; Pauli exclusion and the notion of full orbitals is what makes helium inert, after all.  But the potential would still diverge at small internuclear distances, again due to Coulomb repulsion.
OK so we get a different answer when we replace electrons with bosons here; does this mean that the repulsion is due to Pauli exclusion? That's a question of interpretation. My take is that at the end of the day, all of the energy in the problem is derived from Coulomb interactions. There is no 'Pauli force' showing up to keep the atoms apart. Pauli exclusion only eliminates certain low-energy states from the problem.
Previous answer before I learned that bosonic matter is definitely unstable
To the question "can we construct a scalar model in which we have stable solids? Could those solids be rigid and not pass through each other?" those are hard questions and I don't know the answers. Here are two potential almost-answers though:

Superconductors are still rigid objects, even though their conduction electrons condense into Cooper pairs that almost obey Bose-Einstein statistics.
Superfluid helium becomes a crystalline solid at high pressures, despite its nearby superfluid phase behaving like a Bose-Einstein condensate.
Related to the above, helium 4 may or may not have a supersolid phase, which is a sort of blend of between a superfluid and a solid. I don't know much about it, but it could be an interesting source of further, potentially related reading.


Thanks, but I'm still missing something. I've added links to discussions where the Pauli exclusion principal was invoked in order to explain atomic repulsion at close range. Are they simply wrong, or am I missing something? Can you point to a calculation which quantifies the Pauli effect v.s the Culomb repulsion between nuclei?

I would point you back to Born-Oppenheimer potentials, but I suppose my $\text{H}^2$ example is too simple. I updated my answer to address this and other things.

You could also read the two references that Wikipedia cites for this $N^{7/5}$ stuff. They go into more detail about the actual phase of bosonic matter, which is apparently called jellium!

The elimination of low energy states is a repulsive effect: a force by any sane definition. Without it condensed matter would collapse, as you say.

John Doty, is $\vec{F}=\vec\nabla{V}$ a sane definition of force? Well, yes, it's the definition of force! Pauli exclusion does not come from such a term, so it does not come from repulsion between fermions. It asserts that certain states do not exist in Hilbert space at all. Even if the corresponding fermions are infinitely far apart, their total wave function will be totally antisymmetric. No forces involved.

Oops $\vec{F} = \vec{\nabla}V$ is not a sane definition of force. But $\vec{F} = -\vec{\nabla}V$ is. You know what I mean.

This question is unanswerable and too hypothetical. Nevertheless, trying and failing can elucidate some principles.

The title "scalar QED". Once you bring in QED, as decidedly not scalar theory (spinors and vector boson), there is nothing that can be done, and if we did something: it would not be renormalizable, so our results would be meaning less.

So let's just say charged particles.

but, you mentioned nucleons. Peruse http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Nuclear_Forces and you should convinced to avoid nucleon--I mean the interaction isn't even a central force.

so let's chose an exotic atom, maybe a mix between anti-muonium and positronium: bind an $e^-$ to a $\mu^+$.
Ofc muons are unstable, but their lifetime is long on the some of the atomic timescale. Or we can just "turn-off" the weak interaction, in which case they are stable and only interact with electrons via EM.
And we make them spin zero. If we make the photon scalar too, we can go in with Coulomb atom plus corrections.
Since hyper-fine structure is cause by nuclear spin, we can chuck that.
Fine structure is tricky. Walking through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure, we have:
Kinetic energy relativistic correction
We're still going to have this. If we turn off relativity, we turn off the Spin-Statistics Theorem, which cancels the Pauli exclusion term.
So we pick up an:
$$ H' = -\frac{p^4}{8m_e^3c^2} $$
Probably $m_{\mu}$ is large enough that it doesn't need a correction. If it does, make it a tau.
Spin–orbit coupling
Well, there's no spin, and we made EM a scalar theory: no magnetism, none of this stuff.
Darwin term
This is tricky. It's non-relativistic, but is derived from decidedly spinor Dirac equation. It looks like:
$$ H_{Darwin} = \frac{\hbar^2}{8m_e^2c^2}
4\pi
\big(\frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\big)\delta^3(\vec r) $$
So a delta function at the origin. I think this is a result of the Pauli Exclusion principle via the Dirac eq, but maybe not. Let's chuck it.
So we have two scalar boson hydrogen-like atoms, with the $S$ shell holding infinity electrons.
How do they interact? Is there a Van der Waals force, maybe?
But if we have a bunch of them, they can all be in the same state, so the answer to your question is "yes".
But what does that mean? An atom is a Bohr radius in size, about
$$ a_0 \approx 50,000\,{\rm fermi}$$
Meanwhile, a nucleus is
$$ R_p \approx 1\, {\rm fermi} $$
(ofc, we have a point nucleus here), but an electron has a Compton wavelength
$$ \lambda_C = 2\pi\alpha a_0 \approx 2,400\,
{\rm fermi}$$
so you can't even localize two electrons to the same position on the scale of a nucleus.
Edit: thanks to Rd Basha for the comment. I'm adding the reply here b/c I want my fitty:
So we got scalar structure less charged colorless particles? The localized nuclei is where the strong field it, and they would scatter in the standard manner with zero phase space for =0, but not for $<_$--so what does pass through even mean? If they are identical would they be in a symmetric wave function? Yes--then they wouldn't even have identity, so  and  channel are indistinguishable, there is no "atom 1" and "atom 2". Like I said: too hypothetical, but this is PSE, where it's OK to entertain silliness, since it can elucidate seriousness.
PS: I don't care about scalar QED's renormalizability. It's irrelevant to the question, but is relevant to the class of questions, which is, "non-physical hypotheticals".

Scalar QED (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_electrodynamics) is a specific theory involving a massless vector boson and a charged spin-0 boson. It is a perfectly good renormalizable theory. It has nothing to do with real-world QED. There is nothing wrong with studying this theory and its consequences for atoms. I completely disagree that this question is too hypothetical. A well-defined mathematical model exists in which we can perform calculations through which one should be able to answer OPs questions.

@Prahar: go for it. What are you going to do about the nuclei?

There is no Darwin term for spin 0 particles. The leading relativistic correction only contains the mass-velocity term and the orbit-orbit interaction (for two-body systems); see e.g. arXiv:hep-ph/0111284 for a scalar QED study on pionium. If you make one of the particles mass infinite (representing a heavy spin 0 nucleus), then the orbit-orbit term vanishes too, and only mass-velocity remains (which is already well known from a perturbative treatment of the one-body KG equation).

@JEB - Take the nucleus to be a positively charged scalar particle. The electron orbiting it is a negatively charged scalar particle (with a much smaller mass).

@Prahar so where's your answer?  this why I should stop answering hypotheticals, it just leads to complaining,

@JEB - I don't understand your hostility. I simply stated that your comment that the question is unanswerable is incorrect, which is undeniably true. This is a physics website where we discuss all sorts of physics - including hypotheticals. If you are truly incapable of answering hypotheticals and receiving criticism on those answers, you most definitely should stop answering them (and perhaps ask yourself whether a discussion website is actually for you)

@JEB - Furthermore, this question is not even hypothetical. It is a question about scalar QED, which is a standard theory that EVERY particle physicist studies in their QFT classes. It is most definitely mainstream physics, which puts it well within the rules of this site. What is your problem?

Like I said, all I see is down votes and complaining, and no other answers. None of my QFT professors ever mentioned scalar QED--not once, well, one of them invited QED (RPF), another  just loved $\phi^4$ theories (John Preskill), and last one only cared about the wave function of the universe and traveling the globe (Gell-Mann), but that was just an advance seminar, not a graded class. So I guess my education was insufficient.

@JEB - Yes, it was insufficient, at least for modern times. I could be woefully wrong; based on the names you mentioned, it looks like you took a QFT course quite a long time ago. Obviously that's totally fine. However, I am surprised that, even though you didn't learn it in a QFT course, you haven't at least heard of scalar QED since.

For the record, once name-dropping has entered the vortex, scalar QED was well covered @ Caltech in the mid 70s by Frautschi, of course…

@CosmasZachos I took a class from Frautschi too. I forgot what it was, tho. Maybe "Math methods"? He got T-boned on Maiden Ln and Mariposa in Altadena and was seriously injured. So every time I drove through the intersection (used to live nearby), I thought of him.
